# GTK Frontend for locate

Tags: xfce, gtk, locate

I am a heavy user of the `locate` tool, which is part of the `findutils` package. It's fine to use it on command line, but sometimes I would also like to search for a file (as fast as with `locate`) within my Xfce 4.10 desktop.

Is there any nice GTK frontend (or a panel applet) for the `locate` command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one that I'm most familiar with is called `catfish`. It's generally in most of the standard distros' repos. The main website is here, titled: [Catfish is a versatile file searching tool.](http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php/catfish/). The project's [Launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/catfish-search) is another additional resource if needed.

*excerpt from website*

> Catfish is a search GUI powered by locate and find behind the scenes, with autocompletion from Zeitgeist and locate. The advanced options allow filtering by date and file type. The interface is intentionally lightweight and simple, using only GTK+.

### Example

#### Search

[image: ss #1]

#### Results

[image: ss #2]

#### Advanced filtering

[image: ss #3]