# regex matching with "locate"

Tags: bash, regular-expression, locate

I'm trying to use the locate command to find files in my home folder, however whenever I try and run this I get no results:

```
locate -i -l 4 --regexp '^\/home\/jack\/[A-Za-z0-9\/\ ]*(My.)*$'
```

I've also tried `^\/home\/jack\/^(?!\.)[A-Za-z0-9\/\ ]*(My.)*$` but that returns no results either.

The file I'm looking for just to test it is `/home/jack/Music/Foals/My Number.flac`

I would like to exclude the results of hidden files from my search.

Comment: I am not familiar with `locate`. Does it make sense to combine `-b` (i.e. "Match only the base name against the specified patterns.") with a path in `--regexp`? Why do you escape the `/`s?

Comment: Sorry I was using a regex builder which advised I escape those characters, and I guess you're right about the -b flag, I'll get rid of it now

Comment: What is `(My.)*` supposed to do? `My.*$` works. You have to escape `()` in basic REs.

Comment: You are using an extended regex.  But `--regexp` takes a basic regex.  Try changing `--regexp` to `--regex` (no `p`).  The man page says `--regex` does extended regex matching.

Answer (score 9):

This seems to do the job.

```
locate -ir '^/home/jack/\([^.][^/]\+/\)\+My[^/]*$'
```

Quotes from manual:

> -i, --ignore-case Ignore case distinctions when matching patterns.
>
> -r, --regexp REGEXP Search for a basic regexp REGEXP. No PATTERNs are allowed if this option is used, but this option can be specified
>   multiple times.

Comment: Under Linux, mlocate 0.26-1ubuntu2 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus, as of 2018-02-05), the command returns the following error "locate: non-option arguments are not allowed with --regexp".  mlocate is the actual package (/usr/bin/locate is a symlink to mlocate).

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a different approach:

```
locate "My file" | grep '/home/jack' | grep -v '/\.'
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You're using the `-i` flag to make it case insensitive and your regex is not very specific, you seem top want to find all files or folders that are under `/home/jack` and which contain `MY`, `My`, `my`, or `mY` anywhere in the file name. If so, just run

```
locate -i my | grep '/home/jack' | grep -v '/\.'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work - matches only non-hidden files and folders:

```
find /home/jack -name "[^.]*My.*"
```

even simpler - this matches files that do not have hidden directories anywhere in the directory tree. Probably this is what you want:

```
for f in /home/jack/**/*My.*
    do echo "$f" # or do any other command
done
```

Comment: I would prefer to use `locate`, as I'm trying to integrate it into a Python GUI to search as you type and it's faster. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @JackJones you don't even need `locate` to speed up results. E.g.: `echo /home/jack/**/*My.*`

Answer (score 0):

#### How locate works

The index of files that the `locate` command uses is only rebuilt once a day, typically. It's built by this cron job, `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`. So you entries are likely just not there yet. You can re-run it if you'd like it to manually rebuild these indexes.

```
$ sudo /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

#### Using find

However you're probably better off using a command such as `find` to locate files in your home directory.

```
$ find ~ -iname "[^.]*" | head -10
/home/saml
/home/saml/isql_issue.txt
/home/saml/bbbb
/home/saml/script_name.sh
/home/saml/go_figure_book
/home/saml/go_figure_book/readme.txt
/home/saml/go_figure_book/lstopo.txt
/home/saml/go_figure_book/who_breaks_out.bash
/home/saml/hdat2
/home/saml/hdat2/hdat2_v50.iso
```

#### Using a GUI

You also might be interested in a graphical search tool. Take a look at this other U&L Q&A titled: [GTK Frontend for locate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115417/gtk-frontend-for-locate/115425#115425) which covers one such tool called Catfish. This tool can utilize both `locate` data as well as `find` commands too.

Comment: I often find `locate` faster than `find` even if I have to do an `updatedb` first. As long as the database is already reasonably up to date on most systems `updatedb` won't take long. Find syntax is probably easier in this case though.

Comment: Yeah I used it daily too, it's only on servers where I'm scripting something that I'll often switch to `find`.

Comment: Yeah, should have put 'most desktop systems'