# Is there a way to have Nautilus include mlocate in the results?

Tags: fedora, gnome3, nautilus, locate

When searching for files, I often prefer using locate (because of the speed).

However, I end up opening a terminal just for that purpose and then closing it again. Not a big problem for me, but my girlfriend often forgets command names.

*Is there a way to have Nautilus to use `mlocate` for searching?*

Ideally, I'd love to have the results displayed separately (because a file in `locatedb` may no longer exist), but I'm ok if it doesn't.

Failing that, is there some GUI to locate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not seen a way to incorporate these results into Nautilus, but there are GUIs for search in `mlocate`'s database. The one that I'm most familiar with is called `catfish`. It's generally in most of the standard distros' repos. The main website is here, titled: [Catfish is a versatile file searching tool.](http://www.twotoasts.de/index.php/catfish/). The project's [Launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/catfish-search) is another additional resource if needed.

*excerpt from website*

> Catfish is a search GUI powered by locate and find behind the scenes, with autocompletion from Zeitgeist and locate. The advanced options allow filtering by date and file type. The interface is intentionally lightweight and simple, using only GTK+.

### Example

#### Search

[image: ss #1]

#### Results

[image: ss #2]

#### Advanced filtering

[image: ss #3]

#### References

- [GTK Frontend for locate](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115417/gtk-frontend-for-locate/)